# Change jSlider after certain seconds automatically

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, seconds

I have a Java Swing program where the background programs executes when the jSlider is changed. But the jSlider cannot be changed by human interaction, but it decreases automatically (jSlider represents Concentration Level of a liquid). Once it is decreased, other program reads jSlider by actionListener and provides appropriate solute to meet concentration requirement. I am unable to achieve this scenario. I have tried using thread, but because of my little knowledge probably I am not writing proper code.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new IPS().setVisible(true);

            }
        });

         Thread concentration = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException v)
                {

                }
                sldLevel.setValue(sldLevel.getValue() - 3);
            }
        }; 
        boolean carryOn = true;

        while (carryOn && !btnIPSStart.isEnabled())
        {
            concentration.start();
        }
    }
```

---

***Code Update with Swing Timer***

```
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    new IPS().setVisible(true);

                }
            });

            Timer myTimer = new Timer(100, 1000);
            // I get a error 'int cannot be converted to action listener

            while (myTimer.isRunning)
            {
                sldLevel.setValue(sldLevel.getValue() - 3)
            }
```

Comment: I don't see much relation between your introduction and your code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you assist me on the code.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @user3337714, `can you assist me on the code.` - how could you have possibly read the tutorial in less than one minute? Or how could you have searched the forum for examples that use the Swing Timer?

Comment: @user3337714, Why are you creating a Timer with two int  parameters? Where did you see that in the tutorial? Or where did you see a constructor in the Swing Timer API  that takes two integers as parameters? Reading the API is the way to resolve compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a Thread and you should not use Thread.sleep(). This will cause the GUI to freeze and it won't be able to repaint itself.

Instead you should use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). When the Timer fires you can update the value of the slider.